# The operator ! is undefined for the argument type(s) String java(Android)

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I am using android and had an email field(EditText) from which i will fetch data

**Sample Code**

```
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        String email = input.getText().toString();
        Log.v("><><><><><><>",email);
        if (!email) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert_email = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);   
            alert_email.setMessage("Please enter email.");
            alert_email.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                }
            });
            alert_email.show();
        }
        else {
                    ...........
                    ...........
        }
    }
});
```

When i used `if(!email)` it was displaying error as `The operator ! is undefined for the argument type(s) String java(Android)` but when used (email == null) and it was not coming in to if block and always going to else block

So how to check if the variable has data in java ?

Guys don't downvote it, as i am new to java

Comment: where is operator `!` in your code?

Comment: @Baby edited the code above

Comment: use if(email != null)

Comment: I guess OP want to show dialog, **IF** `email` is `null`

Comment: @shivakrishna If you are new to Java, you should learn the syntax. The compiler tells you that the operator `!` is not suitable for `String` variables. What else do you want to know?

Comment: You should use `StringUtils.isEmpty(string)` from Apache Commons-IO library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A textfield returnd an empty string, so you have to check also if your string is empty:

```
if (email == null || email.trim().length()>0){
```

or

```
if (email == null || email.trim().isEmpty()){
```

The `!` operator is the negation. you can not use it with string. If you whant check if a string is not null, you have to use `email != null`

Comment: How about using .isEmpty() directly on variable ?

Comment: 1) Using `email.isEmpty()` would be better. 2) How does this answer OP's question about the compiler error for `if(!email)`?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose have changed my answer

Comment: @shivakrishna `isEmpty()` only returns true if the string has a length of zero. So if email is a blank isEmpty() returns falso. So it should be trimmed.

Comment: IsEmpty() would also cause null pointer exception on a string that is null

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that's why the `null` check.

Comment: Wow, I should wake up because I totally missed that while I was looking at it. O_o